# Patina peel off on newly seasoned wok

Tags: wok

I just bought a carbon steel wok. I follow seasoning instruction in this video

https://youtu.be/Ch2hhGi-9zc

Basically

1. wash the wok
2. Burn until yellowish blue
3. Add 2 spoons of veg oil , rub with paper towel and burn on very high heat for 10 mins, and repeat this 3 times

After finishing season, the wok looked polishing dark and i was happy.

But when I used it for the first time ,the black patina peel off during cooking. I had to throw away the food.

[image: peeled patina]

My questions are what did i do wrong during seasoning processes and what should I do to rectify it?

Comment: Are you sure the wok didn't come with some sort of non-stick coating?

Comment: Many carbon steel pans & woks come with a waxy or plasticy coating designed to prevent rusting between the manufacturer and you. That anti rust coating needs to be scrubbed and removed before use. My wok came with instructions to boil water in it for a few minutes first, then scrub with a stiff brush or steel wool... Just to remove the coating before seasoning. How thoroughly did you wash your wok before seasoning?

Comment: Welcome to SA!  We have a lot of questions/answers here about wok patina.  Does one of these answer it for you?

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/84247  https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/30808  https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34491
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/58350  https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/94626

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How did I strip the patina off my wok?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/84247/how-did-i-strip-the-patina-off-my-wok)